# How to enable shortcodes in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

How can I enable shortcodes on a custom post type that doesn't use `the_content()` or `get_the_content()`?
In the template file it uses

```
<?php echo nl2br( $post->post_content ); ?>
```

to get the content from the backend like any other post or page would.
I have tried using

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $postid)); ?>
```

which works but the shortcode itself is still displaying for example:

```
[gallery columns="4" link="file" ids="1,2,3,4"]
```

displays above the gallery photos.

Comment: And why doesn’t it use the_content?

Comment: I do not know why it doesn't use the_content.  This is a plugin from WordPress Repository - All In One Video Gallery.

Comment: Then the plugin appears to have been built in such a way that doesn't support shortcodes. You will need to check with the author if there's a workaround.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For my particular situation the answer was to replace `<?php echo nl2br( $post->post_content ); ?>` with `<?php echo $content; ?>` which allowed all shortcodes to work as expected.

Comment: You modified the plugin directly?

Comment: Yes, I modified the plugin directly in one of it's template files.

Comment: The change is going to be erased whenever you update the plugin then.

Comment: Wow.  Yes I know that.  LOL  That's why I save files that have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem because I was rendering content like this:

```
echo get_the_content();
```

Instead of:

```
the_content();
```

The 2nd function must include the shortcode filter.

Answer (score 1):

**Shortcodes** really should run in **custom post types**. Essentially a custom post type is a post. So it sounds like there is a problem filtering shortcodes somewhere.

What is likely happening is that you are using **get_the_content() rather than the_content()** which doesn't filter. Where and how are you displaying the content for the custom post type?

If this is the case, please use get_the_content() function in this way to apply appropriate filtering.

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, 
 $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

**Visit this link for more detail about your Problem**

[wpmudev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/enable-shortcodes-on-custom-post-types)

Comment: I had already tried that from wpmudev and that did not work either.  The plugin author is fixing this issue in the next update.  Like I said earlier, For my particular situation the answer was to replace `<?php echo nl2br( $post->post_content ); ?> ` with `<?php echo $content; ?>` which allowed all shortcodes to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `apply_filters()` to let WordPress process the shortcodes in your content.

`<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>`

Comment: This did not work.  I got a blank page when using this which said the connection had been reset.

Comment: Try passing the result from `nl2br( $post->post_content )` through `apply_filters()`: `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', nl2br( $post->post_content ) ); ?>` and see what happens.

Comment: No, that did not work either.  Same result.  I did try `<?php echo $content; ?>` in place of `<?php echo nl2br( $post->post_content ); ?>` and the shortcodes are now displaying as expected. Thanks